# How to set CanvasText color in Windows to properly reflect in web browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge)?

Tags: windows, windows-7, firefox, colors, css

Modern web browsers (Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge, et al.) can be configured to use colours (colors) set by the operating system.  They do this by using named colours such as `ThreeDShadow`, `ThreeDHighlight`, `ButtonHighlight`, and `CanvasText` (not to be confused with the `<canvas>` HTML element).

This works well and good when the OS exposes the colours to the user via a UI and allows the user to modify the colours to suit their needs.

But where in Windows 7 can one set the ***all-important*** `CanvasText` color?

The answer seems to be an enigma and is not found in the answers to [this relevant Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268424/is-there-a-visual-guide-to-system-windows-systemcolors), which include [this excellent table](https://web.archive.org/web/20071210050943/http://www.brethorsting.com/resources/syscolors.html) and [this Microsoft reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wpf/systemcolors-reference).

Answer (score 1):

`CanvasText` is used only in forced-color mode i.e. in high-contrast modes, and in such mode corresponds to `Text`, as you can [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/design-system/high-contrast).

[Read here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2022/03/windows-high-contrast-colors-mode-css-custom-properties/) for more information about forced-colour schemes.

And [this article](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/09/17/styling-for-windows-high-contrast-with-new-standards-for-forced-colors/) describes more about how to use it in CSS.

I cannot test this in Windows 7, but you should be [able to set a high-contrast colour scheme](https://www.microcenter.com/tech_center/article/4516/how-to-toggle-high-contrast-mode-in-windows-7), which will activate the `CanvasText` .

Comment: Upvoted and bounty awarded.  Thank you for the details.